# MyBatis Cursor with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm trying to use a MyBatis Cursor with Spring Boot to iterate a large query:

Mapper:

```
@Mapper
@Repository
interface UserMapper {

    @Select("SELECT * FROM huge_user_table")
    Cursor<User> getUsers();
```

Consumer:

```
@Component
public class UserProcessor {
    @Autowired private UserMapper userMapper;

    public boolean process() throws IOException {
        Cursor<User> users = userMapper.getUsers();
        //users.isOpen() == false
        for (User user : users) {
            //Never iterates
            System.out.println(user.getId());
        }
```

When I get my cursor back though it is closed, with no records returned.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most probably the problem is that you try to use `Cursor` outside of transaction. This is not supported.

`Cursor` is basically a wrapper around JDBC `ResultSet`. In order to fetch values from `Cursor` the underlying `ResultSet` should be opened. If you do not have a transaction for the whole duration of the loop then spring will open the connection when the query is executed (in your case for the duration of `getUsers` method). After the method is finished the connection is closed and therefore the `ResultSet` used by `Cursor` is closed as well.

Add `@Transactional` to `process` and this should fix the issue.