# mybatis cursor mysql No operations allowed after statement closed

Tags: java, mysql, cursor, mybatis

I'm trying to use a MyBatis Cursor with Spring Boot2.0.3(mybatis3.5.4,mybatis-plus3.1.2,duridjdbc1.1.21,mysql-connect5.0.17) to iterate a large query. 
for Mysql
i saw [MyBatis Cursor with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51655126/mybatis-cursor-with-spring-boot)
but it is still not work.

xml:

```
<select id="fetchListByCreateDate" fetchSize="-2147483648"  statementType="PREPARED" resultSetType="FORWARD_ONLY" resultType="entityClass">
     SELECT
     *
     FROM table
     ORDER BY create_date DESC
 </select>
```

the Service:

```
    @Override
    @Transactional //**delete it**
    //**change it to** List<entityClass> ......
    public Cursor<entityClass> fetchListByCreateDate() {
        return this.mapper.fetchListByCreateDate();
    }
```

when i invoke

```
        //**change it** List<entityClass> item = serivce.fetchListByCreateDate();
        Cursor<entityClass> item = serivce.fetchListByCreateDate();
        Iterator<entityClass> iter = item.iterator();
        List<entityClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            // Fetch next 10 employees
            for (int i = 0; i < 100 && iter.hasNext(); i++) {
                list.add(iter.next());
            }
            list.clear();
        }
```

then:

```
Cause: java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed.
; ]; No operations allowed after statement closed.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed.

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:110)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:446)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy152.selectCursor(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectCursor(SqlSessionTemplate.java:206)
```

change Cursor to List then the Mybatis will read all data.

Comment: As the linked answer says, you cannot return `Cursor` from the `@Transactional` method. Try rewriting the method to return `List` instead. Also, there was an [issue](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/1654) when using `Cursor` with `fetchSize="-2147483648"`, so be sure to use MyBatis version 3.5.3 or later.

Comment: @ave Hi,i upgrade mybaits to 3.5.4, and change Cursor<entityClass> fetchListByCreateDate to List<entityClass> delete @ Transactional ,Mybatis will read all data.